# How to take numbers after a certain character with file scanners in Java?

Tags: java

So, I'm making a program that gets a bunch of numbers, does some math, puts them in a file, and then hopefully takes them out.
The printing to the file is fine, and results in this:

```
!345
?298
!209
?720
etc.
```

I want to take numbers with "!'s" before them and put them in one array, and numbers with "?'s" before them and put them in another array.
I tried this:

```
long num2 = diskScanner.findWithinHorizon("!", 3);
```

But then it wants to take the exclamation point! I searched online for how the Scanner methods work to no avail.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: why not use the Scanner to get each line from the file, and then use `String` methods to extract the information from each line? Please show a little more effort and code attempt.

Comment: Better yet, assign each number to the appropriate array before you even write it to file.